# Is there a penalty to using functions over function variables when writing a React Function Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Consider the definition of the following two React function components in TypeScript:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface ComponentProps {
    // props omitted for sake of brevity.
}

export function MyComponent1(props: ComponentProps): JSX.Element {
    // Use hooks and return elements for Virtual DOM.
    // Omitted for sake of brevity.
}

export const MyComponent2: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    // Use hooks and return elements for Virtual DOM.
    // Omitted for sake of brevity.
}
```

Is there a benefit of using one over the other, especially with respect to performance? I assume not as the [official React docs also use JS functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). My colleagues and I prefer the syntax of MyComponent1 because it is shorter. But when reading about React online (particularly in blog posts and in Open Source projects), we almost exclusively see the syntax of MyComponent2. Is this just a difference in style?

Comment: Note if you're using `FC<PropType>` you don't need to repeat the type in `(props: PropType)`. Then there's no length difference.

Comment: I think the difference is the same one between "classic" functions and arrow functions, regardless of the framework: the behaviour of the `this` keyword. My colleagues and I tend to prefer arrow functions for that reason.

Comment: @Secan Thanks for your explanation. Do you mind if I ask why you would use `this` in a function component or custom hook? I have never encountered the need to do that.

Comment: I think up until now we never used `this` in a function component (and I cannot think of any use case) but we used it in custom hooks exposed by controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is all about TS compiler performance.

Take a look at TS [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#using-type-annotations):

> Adding type annotations, especially return types, can save the compiler a lot of work. In part, this is because named types tend to be more compact than anonymous types (which the compiler might infer), which reduces the amount of time spent reading and writing declaration files (e.g. for incremental builds). Type inference is very convenient, so there's no need to do this universally - however, it can be a useful thing to try if you've identified a slow section of your code.

Please keep in mind, I'm talking about TS compiler performance, not about performance of your code.

Anyway, all functions will be compiled to:

```js
export function MyComponent1(props) {
    // Use hooks and return elements for Virtual DOM.
    // Omitted for sake of brevity.
}
export const MyComponent2 = (props) => {
    // Use hooks and return elements for Virtual DOM.
    // Omitted for sake of brevity.
};
```

According to TS wiki, adding return type makes compiler a bit faster.

So you can use:

```js
export const MyComponent2: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    // Use hooks and return elements for Virtual DOM.
    // Omitted for sake of brevity.
}
```

if you want to reduce your compile time

Comment: Given that the function type `React.FC<T>` *includes* the return type, I don't think this applies; I wouldn't expect `export const MyComponent3: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props: ComponentProps):JSX.Element => ...` to compile any faster than `export const MyComponent3: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => ...` (the compiler doesn't need to *infer* the return type, just validate it) but it's definitely more typing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how about: `Adding type annotations, especially return types, can save the compiler a lot of work.` ?

Comment: It saves it a lot of work vs. inferring the return type from an otherwise untyped function, but that's **not** what's happening here. The function *has* a type, with a return type; it's `FC`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got your point, You are absolutely right. Did not think about that. `FC` has already return type in itself. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: But now the first section doesn't relate at all to what the OP's asking. If they had `function MyComponent1(props: ComponentProps): JSX.Element { ...` vs. `function MyComponent3(props: ComponentProps) { ...` it might be relevant, but both of their examples *have* return types. So *is* there a difference in compiler performance between their two choices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225948/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-jonrsharpe).